# Data context in Meteor's Template.rendered callback randomly disappears on hot code push

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Short version:

`Session.get()`, and `Template.currentData()` that are supposed to be passed to the template by the Router often turn out to be `undefined` in `Template.<templateName>.render` callback. This happens quite randomly, most often on hot code pushes, but not always, and not only on hot code pushes.

Longer version:

I'm using Iron Router to pass data context to the template `appBody`:

```
Router.route('/:_mapid', function() {
  if (!isNaN(this.params._mapid)) {
    Session.set('currentMap',Maps.findOne({mapid: Number(this.params._mapid)}));
    this.render('appBody', {
        data: function() {  return Session.get("currentMap") }
    });
  }
});
```

The template then uses d3 to generate a bunch of div's, and set the dynamic page title in `Template.appBody.rendered` callback:

```
   Template.appBody.rendered = function() {
    Deps.autorun(function() {
      d3.select("#map_body").selectAll("div").remove();

      d3.select("#map_body").selectAll("div")
      .data(Nodes.find({mapid: Template.currentData().mapid }).fetch(), function(d) {return d.nodeparentid;})
      .enter().append("div")
        .attr("id", function(d){return "node"+ d.nodeparentid})
        .style("position","absolute")
        .style("top",function(d) {return d.toppos+"px"})
        .style("left",function(d) {return d.leftpos+"px"})
        .style("width",function(d) {return d.width+"px"})
        .style("height",function(d) {return d.height+"px"})
        .classed("node", true)

       document.title = "Map - " + Session.get("currentMap").title;

    }
```

As you can see I try to pass the data context to the template in two different ways: by setting a global `currentMap` object via `Session.set` and by passing `data` key via the Router, and then accessing it via `Template.currentData()` method.

For some reason both of these method often fail (although I still can't figure out under what conditions). Here is a sample error I get from the browser console when trying to set a document title:

```
Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at http://localhost:3000/client/templates/app_body.js?47b256634607ca16879aa0ed823593aec01ee840:122:31
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
    at new Tracker.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:206:10)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:476:11)
    at Template.appBody.rendered (http://localhost:3000/client/templates/app_body.js?47b256634607ca16879aa0ed823593aec01ee840:117:10)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2970:21)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1720:14
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2029:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1719:15
    at Tracker.flush (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:438:11)
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: This looks like a race condition where `Maps.findOne` is returning `undefined` because the map isn't published yet. I think you need to [wait on](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#waiting-on-subscriptions) the subscription.

Comment: @DavidWeldon, that seems to have helped. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DavidWeldon, I'm sorry to say, but I just got the same error again. If it's not the race condition, what else could it be?

Comment: Maybe try adding [a guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) like `var map = Session.get("currentMap"); var title = map && map.title;`